# Should I be doing anything to help manage linker namespace pollution WRT internal-use classes?

Tags: c++

In a complex library or framework, there are obviously times when classes are needed purely internally, to implement higher level functionality.

Often these internals are tightly coupled to how the internals work, so there is no point in making them available to users - all they could do with them is to try to tamper with your private internals.

At the same time, some of these things are quite large - easily large enough to require their own separate header and body source files.

If you have a small class within a single file, you can wrap it in an anonymous namespace, and a well-behaved compiler will not include symbols related to that class in the object file. The issue of namespace pollution is completely avoided.

As soon as the class is separately compiled, however, this cannot work - we need to link our other internal implementation code to this object file, so it must contain the relevant symbols.

As the header file is intended for internal use only, it should probably live in the same folder as all the body source files, as opposed to some separate `include` folder that holds the header files users will `#include`.

The symbols are still visible in the object library, though.

Is this a real problem, or an imaginary one? What (if anything) should I be doing to manage this form of namespace pollution?

Comment: Are you actually encountering problems with whatever you are doing at the moment? If not, don't do anything - about the only principle of Agile/XP development I more or less wholly agree with is YAGNI.

Comment: @Neil - it's part of this new system I have. When I feel nervous about something, as if I'm doing the wrong thing, once I would have wasted time worrying about it or trying to construct some clever but impractical fix. These days, I ask a question on SO, get embarrassed about how daft the question looks, and maybe have a blazing row about some irrelevance. I'm not certain which way wastes more time, but the blazing row part can be more fun ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put such identifiers into a `details` namespace:

```
namespace some_component {
  namespace details {
    class helper { ... };
  }
}
```

`some_component::details::helper` is obviously an implementation detail.

Comment: +1 - the chance of a name collision is obviously remote when you do that. I still have that paranoid feeling that something bad will happen, though, just because the symbols are there.

Comment: @Steve As a c++ library creator it is your job to document & warn against misuse of your library from C++ code that calls it. There is no way, at the end of the day, of preventing misuse of compiled code, which is what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: @Steve: When users attempt to make use something with the name `...::details::helper` and the thing blows up into their face, then that's those users' fault.

Comment: that wasn't what I was thinking of. I'm not sure what I *was* thinking of, though - just "something bad". I guess one thought is that someone disassembling a proprietary library will get more clue as a result of those symbols, but I doubt that's a serious issue for many people. It's probably easier to write libraries from scratch rather than reverse engineering someone elses, other than maybe checking which external APIs they call.